# How To Properly Phrase "Knocked Out."

Tags: phrase-requests, phrasing

In a scene from my book, a character, Nastia, has been shot and she's taking small steps to a staircase. But as she staggers, at one point, she can't handle the pain so she tumbles down the stairs and knocks out. With the way I phrased it below, I just don't feel like it gives off a very professional or emotional vibe to it. Are there any suggestions on how to properly phrase the ending? (In bold).

> Small steps carried Nastia towards a staircase, as if she'd forgotten
>   how to walk. But it wasn't that. She had forgotten what it felt like
>   to be free and for the first time in a long time, felt painfully
>   liberated. **She staggered until she could no longer handle the pain and
>   tumbled down the staircase, knocking out.**

As I said above, it doesn't seem to be the most professional in terms of how it's phrased. I also don't feel like it gives off the vibe of the emotional scene, just because of word choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Blacking out** is the phrase I believe you're looking for, meaning ["to become unconscious."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/black+out)

The example given by the link is:

> After I fell, I must have *blacked out*.

Comment: A person may black out for many different reasons -- excessive consumption of alcohol, strangulation, shock.  "Knock out" requires a blow, either literally as in a punch, or figuratively, as in something equivalent in force like chloral hydrate.

Comment: Or "passed out" due to pain or blood loss, not dissimilar to "blacked out."

Answer (score 3):

If you want to using "knocking," you'll have to grammatically deliver a blow to make the person unconscious.  You have several choices:

**Active voice**:

> She tumbled down the staircase, the fall **knocking** her out.

**Passive voice**:

> She tumbled down the staircase.  She **was knocked** out by the fall.

**Reflexive**:

> She tumbled down the staircase, **knocking herself** out.